# Select 3 Different Columns (COUNT) from 3 different tables and group by Date

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, pivot

I have 3 different tables called that tracks the number of pens sold, pencils sold and ink sold.

```
**pens table:**
date         who_bought
12.03.2020   a
12.03.2020   d
13.03.2020   b
14.03.2020   c

**pencils table:**
date         who_bought
12.03.2020   z
16.03.2020   r
17.03.2020   j
17.03.2020   k

**ink table:**
date         who_bought
11.03.2020   h
11.03.2020   j
13.03.2020   z
17.03.2020   r
```

I want to aggregate data and get for each day, how many pens, inks and pencils I sold. The "who_bought" column is not relevant (I mean the values). I just want to count the number of records for each day. finally, I want to sort by date.
In the above case, I would like to get results like

```
11.03.2020 pens:0 pencils:0 ink: 2
12.03.2020 pens:2 pencils:1 ink: 0
13.03.2020 pens:1 pencils:0 ink:1
14.03.2020 pens:0 pencils:0 ink:0
16.03.2020 pens:0 pencils:1 ink:0
17.03.2020 pens:0 pencils:2 ink:1
```

How can this be achieved?
 I tried something like this, but it's not working:

```
select
    COUNT(pens.*) as pens,
    COUNT(pencils.*) as pencils,
    COUNT(ink.*) as ink,
    DATE(date) as date
from
    pens
    full join pencils on pencils.date=pens.date
    full join ink on ink.date=pens.date
group by
    date
order by
    date asc
```

Comment: "but it's not working" is not an adequate problem description. Please explain **how** it's not working. Do you get an error from your DBMS? Do you get unexpected results?

Comment: This seems like a flawed design . You are not 'on the right track'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt using `full join` is on the right track; unfortunately, MySQL does not support this syntax.

You could do this with `union all` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    date,
    sum(what = 'pens')    no_pens,
    sum(what = 'pencils') no_pencils,
    sum(what = 'ink')     no_inks
from (
    select 'pens' what, date from pens
    union all select 'pencils', date from pencils
    union all select 'ink', date from ink
) t
group by date
```

If you want all dates, including those for which no sale happened for any product, then it is a bit different. Basically, ou need a calendar table for this. Here is one way to do it with a recursive query (available in MySQL 8.0 only).

```
with dates as (
    select min(date) date, max(date) max_date
    from (
        select date from pens
        union all select date from pencils
        union all select date from ink
    ) t
    union all 
    select date + interval 1 day from cte where date < max_date
)
select 
    d.date, 
    pn.no_pens, 
    pl.no_pencils,
    ik.no_inks 
from dates d
left join (select date, count(*) no_pens    from pens    group by date) pn on pn.date = d.date
left join (select date, count(*) no_pencils from pencils group by date) pl on pl.date = d.date
left join (select date, count(*) no_inks    from inks    group by date) ik on ik.date = d.date
```

Comment: @BlasterGod: the (first) query only has one derived table, and it is aliased `t`. I don't think that this query would raise this error.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working perfect. For dates that did not happen, I implemented a solution in PHP to "fix" it and still get results. But I will try your approach and see how it works. About the "derived table" issue, I missed the alias 't' initially.